# Google.Cloud.Logging.V2: LogNameOneof

Tags: .net-core, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I am writing a .Net Core utility that is basically a wrapper that will push messages/logs to GCP Stackdriver. There is also a reference to the code on the Google.cloud site

Here is the code:

```
using System;
// Imports the Google Cloud Logging client library
using Google.Cloud.Logging.V2;
using Google.Cloud.Logging.Type;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Google.Api;

namespace GoogleCloudSamples
{
    public class QuickStart
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Your Google Cloud Platform project ID.
            string projectId = "YOUR-PROJECT-ID";

            // Instantiates a client.
            var client = LoggingServiceV2Client.Create();

            // Prepare new log entry.
            LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry();
            string logId = "my-log";
            LogName logName = new LogName(projectId, logId);
            LogNameOneof logNameToWrite = LogNameOneof.From(logName);
            logEntry.LogName = logName.ToString();
            logEntry.Severity = LogSeverity.Info;
...
```

My question is with this line `LogNameOneof logNameToWrite = LogNameOneof.From(logName);` - I get an error with, *LogNameOneof*, has anyone else been able to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed the recent changes that were made on github that portrays this configuration and it appears that “LogNameOneof logNameToWrite = LogNameOneof.From(logName);” has been replaced by “ logEntry.LogNameAsLogName = logName;”. This change can be viewed from the recent [cleanup](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/commit/99aa406af33d5674f36779d3089eb54d71bc78c0) that was done on April 6th.